# How to display Database data using Angular JS?

Tags: database, angularjs, web-applications

How to handle mapping DB Tables to Angular Display which I think is one of the most common requirements in WebApps ?

There are several factors that needs to be considered .

1)For displaying the records , a 2D JSON would be fine ?

Like for example :

```
var myList = function($scope){
    $scope.foods = [
        {name:"Pizza" , price:100},
        {name:"Pasta" , price:50},
        {name:"Burger" , price:30},
        {name:"Pepsi" , price:10},
        {name:"Icecream" , price:15}
       ]
    };
```

And for the refresh the view part , Is it good idea to sent a JSON of Primary IDN's for refreshing the view form Server ?

2) Where should pagination be handled . I think a complete server side pagination is won't take advantage of  Angular's front end capabilities like Filter ?

Short data say < 1000 records would probably be better sent to server , While large data like 'search' can be paginated server side would be a good trade off ?

For example :

```
Table : Student


IDN Name  Univeristy Age 
1   Mark  USC        21
2   ...
3   ...
4   John  UFL        21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array of objects is absolutely fine, and easy to use inside `ngRepeat`. When refreshing the data, the logic is up to you - you can either send the indices to refresh (and then update them in your model when needed) or just request a new response from the backend. The latter is obviously easier, but whether it's actually better depends on your app and your requirements. In order to reduce resource usage, remember to use `track by` on your `ngRepeat`:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users track by user.id">
        <!-- data -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

As for the pagination, what I usually do is to set up pagination on the front end and send out `limit` and `offset` params to the backend server with each request. The only thing to remember is that the backend must return the requested data AND the total number of items in the queried table. I usually prefer to send this number in a header so that all data is sent in one request. Based on the knowledge Angular.js has (current limit, offset and total number of items), pagination can be implemented with little effort.

Comment: Interesting perceptive . I agree the logic is for us to decide and hence the question :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ng-grid` http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/
Basically you just send a JSON array of objects from the server, like your `foods` example

To support large datasets you can setup server-side pagination, filtering and sorting on `ng-grid`, you accomplish that by sending a `params` object back to the server that has the page/filter/sort information you will need on the server API to return the specific data e.g.

`$http({
  url: "/api/foods",
  method: "GET",
  params: myPageSortFilter
})`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out in ng-grid , would be curious to check how different it is from ng-repeat .